# How to manage time in react and nodejs without problem of timezone

Tags: node.js, reactjs, momentjs, mern, moment-timezone

I have done all ways to evaluate time in my mern application. Still can't find the solution and wasn't also able to find any solution in the internet to...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the Date from a specific timezone you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

From their doc:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Basically you have to decide if you want to use your server side timezone and then convert it in the frontend to the user's timezone, or if you want to use only one timezone, depending on the use case.